# How to handle updates changing versions in old answers

Tags: discussion, answers, suggested-edits

I don't know if this has been discussed before, or if the answer is obvious (excuse my ignorance), but I've seen a couple of suggested changes on SO, where the only thing changed is a version number and/or a reference, and I'm unsure whether or not to accept it.

For instance, assume an old answer refers to the [MySQL documentation, version 5.0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/), and  a suggested edit changes that link and title to the [5.6 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/) with a short comment about it - should such a change generally be accepted or rejected? (Note, just to be clear: This obviously goes for apps, plugins, frameworks, and whatever else too - not just documentation)

My general feeling is that in most cases, such changes should be rejected. I feel I should leave the answer as it is, given that it is dated anyway, and should be read in the context of the question (and the date on that). Ironically, I'm not always sure whether to reject it as a "radical change", or because it is a "too minor"...

I suppose an exception to the above might be in general very cases; something like:

```
PS: You can find further documentation about MySQL here: <link>
```

...in which case a ref. to the most recent version might be relevant.

Am I making any sense? Any strong opinions or guidelines?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149190/should-i-avoid-adding-updates-to-accepted-answers-to-old-questions, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131495/how-to-handle-outdated-answers, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144786/how-to-deal-with-questions-with-a-highly-voted-answer-outdated-and-a-lowly-vot or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149014/what-do-you-do-when-a-question-or-answer-becomes-outdated (and take your pick of duplicate).

Comment: **"short comment"** could be a sufficient reason to reject such an edit; not because the edit is wrong but because short comments indicate careless attitude. If editor doesn't bother to just clearly explain [**why** the edit was made](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160777/165773 "as discussed eg here"), what else could be wrong there?

Comment: FWIW, my strong opinion is that you should never *change* version numbers or references for answers which become outdated. Add to them by all mean ("oh btw, you can now do it this way since version 4.5.6"), but never *change* an answer like this. Here's an example of a answer I coincidentally updated yesterday; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768183/click-event-not-working-in-jquery/7768207#7768207